# How to force IDA to understand that a given literal value is the bitwise combination of enum members?

Tags: ida, hexrays

I have an `.so` file which uses the dynamic linker with `dlopen` and friends. So the values for `RTLD_*` used in `dlopen` are of relevance to me. The standard imported enum in IDA looks like this:

```
FFFFFFFF ; enum MACRO_RTLD, mappedto_62, signed, width 8 bytes
FFFFFFFF RTLD_LOCAL       = 0
FFFFFFFF RTLD_DEFAULT     = 0
FFFFFFFF RTLD_LAZY        = 1
FFFFFFFF RTLD_NOW         = 2
FFFFFFFF RTLD_BINDING_MASK  = 3
FFFFFFFF RTLD_NOLOAD      = 4
FFFFFFFF RTLD_DEEPBIND    = 8
FFFFFFFF RTLD_GLOBAL      = 100h
FFFFFFFF RTLD_NODELETE    = 1000h
FFFFFFFF RTLD_NEXT        = -1
```

Attempting to mark this as a bitfield I get:

> Can't convert bitfield <-> enum, some constants hinder.

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The value I see passed to `dlopen` and which I would like to represent a bit more obviously is 257 or 0x101, so `RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL`.

Alright, so I thought to myself I'd remove the names which combine more than a single bit. But I also needed to remove two more enum members (those with value `0`).

**Question:** Is there any way I can make IDA or the Hex-Rays plugin understand that this "macro" (enum) assigns symbolic names to bitwise combinations of those enum members *without* having to cripple the (copied) standard enum and placing those items that I remove into a separate enum?

Obviously this isn't a bit field in the strict sense, but the enum members are still meant to be combined bitwise. And it should/would be possible to deduce the symbolic form from the value.

Comment: Yep, the answer is no. This is probably because IDA has to create references to those enumerations when they're applied, but this is just speculation.

However, you shouldn't need to remove both "0" members. When you create your bitfield, add a new value with "mask" to 3 (you can name it "RTLD_BINDING_MASK" even), and then when you create your `RTLD_DEFAULT` (or whatev) enum you can specify its __value__ as "0" for the wanted mask. Then for `RTLD_GLOBAL` (0x100), create the `RTLD_LOCAL` field with the mask set to 0x100 but value as 0x0. This way you still get the correct references anyways.